# Is there better and quicker way to fill only arc of circle (in pixels)?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is there better and quicker way to fill only arc of circle ?
I passed to function coordinates of center, radius, min and max angle(arc angles).
At the moment I returns all pixels inside circle (x,y,r) and checks if angle of point between angles insert in result.
//lineTo (bresenham) is function which returns points between two pixels

```
float calculateAngle(float x0, floaty0, float x1, float y1);// returns angle between two points and x axis

std::set< std::pair<int,int> > Board::getFilledCellsinRadius(const int x,const int y,const int r, float alpha1, float alpha2)
{
    std::set< std::pair<int,int> > result;
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int counter=(y+r);
    for(int count=(y-r);count<=counter;count++)
    {
        x1=int(x+sqrt(static_cast<double>((r*r)-((count-y)*(count-y)))+0.5));
        x2=int(x-sqrt(static_cast<double>((r*r)-((count-y)*(count-y)))+0.5));

        std::set< std::pair<int,int> > temp=lineTo(x1,count,x2,count);
        for(std::set< std::pair<int,int> >::iterator iter=temp->begin();iter!=temp->end();++iter){
            float a=calculateAngle(x,y,(*iter).first, (*iter).second);
            if(a>=alpha1 && a<=alpha2){
               result.insert(*iter);
             }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: By fill the arc you mean entire area of the arc? or just draw the arc itself?

Comment: wait is your function returning all points inside the arc so you can fill those points?

Comment: @user814628 Yes, all points inside arc

Comment: Do you necessarily need all points? You can use flood fill algorithm to draw a filled arc as long as you have the outline of the arc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you return points on the arc and then use the lineto function to fill in the arc?

Points on the arc should be calculable mathematically, this would avoid unnecessary calculations.

Alternatively, draw the arc and the 2 radii and use a [Flood Fill Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) to fill it in, thanks @user814628

Comment: I am not sure if that is going to fill every inside, based on line to it can be some halls inside because it is discrete

Comment: @PaolaJ. Have you tried? The points will go further apart as they move away from the radius, thus all points on the radial lines are closer to each other than the points on the arc. Thus theoretically, as long as you cover all pixels on the arc, you should cover all points within.